# Joining and filtering two sets of the same table

Tags: mysql, relational-division

I guess this is an easy and stupid question. Consider this MySQL `purchase` table (where `p_id` is autoincremented):

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|   p_id  |    item_id  |  user_id      | count   | ... 
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|       1 | 4           |             1 |       22|
|       2 | 4           |             2 |        1|
|       3 | 1           |             1 |        1|
|       4 | 0           |             3 |        1|
|       5 | 3           |             1 |      182|
|       6 | 0           |             4 |        1|
|       7 | 3           |             2 |        7|
|       8 | 3           |             2 |       14|
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
```

What's an appropriate way (query) to get the rows where the users whose ids are 1 and 2 have purchased the same items, and only retrieved their last purchase of those items?
The result should be something like this:

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|    p_id |    item_id  |  user_id      | count   | ... 
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|       1 | 4           |             1 |       22|
|       2 | 4           |             2 |        1|
|       5 | 3           |             1 |      182|
|       8 | 3           |             2 |       14|
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: This is not a stupid question at all. You stumbled upon one of the more tricky problems in SQL: [relational division](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/relational-division/info). We assembled an arsenal of related query techniques under [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation). But please define more closely what you mean by `only retrieved their last purchase of those items`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

1. `p_id` is unique
2. 'last purchase' is defined by highest `p_id`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7910/10)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t(p_id integer, item_id integer, user_id integer, cnt integer);

insert into t(p_id, item_id, user_id, cnt) values(1,4,1,22);
insert into t(p_id, item_id, user_id, cnt) values(2,4,2,1);
insert into t(p_id, item_id, user_id, cnt) values(3,1,1,1);
insert into t(p_id, item_id, user_id, cnt) values(4,0,3,1);
insert into t(p_id, item_id, user_id, cnt) values(5,3,1,182);
insert into t(p_id, item_id, user_id, cnt) values(6,0,4,1);
insert into t(p_id, item_id, user_id, cnt) values(7,3,2,7);
insert into t(p_id, item_id, user_id, cnt) values(8,3,2,14);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from( select *
      from t tt
      where user_id=1 and p_id=( select max(p_id)
                                 from t
                                 where user_id=1 and item_id=tt.item_id )
      union all
      select *
      from t tt
      where user_id=2 and p_id=( select max(p_id)
                                 from t
                                 where user_id=2 and item_id=tt.item_id ) ) u
where item_id in(select item_id from t where user_id=1)
      and item_id in(select item_id from t where user_id=2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7910/10/0)**:

```
| P_ID | ITEM_ID | USER_ID | CNT |
|------|---------|---------|-----|
|    1 |       4 |       1 |  22 |
|    5 |       3 |       1 | 182 |
|    2 |       4 |       2 |   1 |
|    8 |       3 |       2 |  14 |
```

Answer (score 2):

For lack of information, I make the [same assumptions as @Jack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55610/3684):

1. `p_id` is unique.
2. 'last purchase' is defined by highest `p_id`.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   t
JOIN  (
    SELECT min(p_id) AS p_id1
          ,max(p_id) AS p_id2
    FROM  (
        SELECT user_id, item_id, max(p_id) AS p_id
        FROM   t
        WHERE  user_id IN (1,2)
        GROUP  BY user_id, item_id
        ) sub1
    GROUP  BY item_id
    HAVING count(*) = 2           -- for two user_ids
    ) sub2 ON t.p_id = sub2.p_id1
           OR t.p_id = sub2.p_id2
ORDER  BY t.p_id;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de8ed/3)

This form avoids correlated subqueries, which should therefore perform better. It works well for *two* IDs at a time, but not for more.

Could be much simpler if MySQL supported [CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/cte/info) or [window functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/window-functions/info) like other modern RDBMS. Or even [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) (Postgres specific).

Answer (score 0):

The query that you are looking for, might be similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    pp1 . *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        purchase
    WHERE
        user_id IN (1 , 2)
    ORDER BY p_id DESC) pp
    GROUP BY pp.user_id , pp.item_id
    ORDER BY pp.p_id) pp1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        purchase
    WHERE
        user_id IN (1 , 2)
    ORDER BY p_id DESC) pp
    GROUP BY pp.user_id , pp.item_id
    ORDER BY pp.p_id) pp2 ON pp1.item_id = pp2.item_id
        AND pp1.user_id != pp2.user_id
ORDER BY pp1.p_id;
```